# Unable to enter and select option in custom combobox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried to enter the value(search Engine) and select the option in combo box. Unable to enter and select option in combo box.

Tried with to click first using

```
js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("$(\"#divProfileSetting li:nth-child(2) span\").click()");
```

Here is the HTML source,

```
<div class="controls" id="divSearchEngine">
<div class="k-widget k-multiselect k-header span12" unselectable="on" style="">
<div class="k-multiselect-wrap k-floatwrap" unselectable="on">
<ul role="listbox" unselectable="on" class="k-reset" id="searchEngine_taglist"></ul>
<input class="k-input k-readonly" style="width: 157px;" accesskey="" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="searchEngine_taglist searchEngine_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false">
<span class="k-icon k-loading k-loading-hidden"></span>
</div>
<select class="span12" id="searchEngine" multiple="multiple" name="searchEngine" data-role="multiselect" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" style="display: none;">
<option value="1:AF">Google Afghanistan</option>
<option value="1:AX">Google Åland</option>
<option value="1:AL">Google Albania</option>
</select>
<span style="font-family: CenturyRegular; font-size: 12px; font-stretch: 100%; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none; line-height: 15.72px; position: absolute; visibility: hidden; top: -3333px; left: -3333px;">Select Search Engine...</span>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have issue with selecting the item from the `select` node? Have you checked in the chrome console if the js is working with the provided css?

Comment: you should be able to select the list item using `//select[@id='searchEngine']/option[.='Google Albania']`, without using JS.

Answer (score 0):

```
 js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
    js.executeScript("$('#searchEngine-list ul li:eq(1)').click()"); 
    js=null;
```

This code worked